# after changing the yaw in the map.yaml, costmap does not take that yaw

Tags: navigation, mapping, ros-melodic, map-server, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the below yaml for getting the map using the map_server package. I changed the yaw in the origin tag of the original yaml to -0.102.

```
map_zone.yaml
image: map_zone.pgm
resolution: 0.050000 
origin: [-17.000000, -17.000000, 0.0]   #### OLD
origin: [-17.000000, -17.000000, -0.102000] 
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
```

This change resulted into weird costmap. Please help. My setup is a typical ros navstack using move_base. this also affects amcl slam as localization is way off.

I have already played around with /initial_pose. the setup works fine if i do not change the yaw in the map.yaml file.

with original yaw=0.0
[image: with original zero yaw]

with yaw = -0.0102
[image: With yaw](/upfiles/16046623663103974.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364928/after-changing-the-yaw-in-the-map.yaml,-costmap-does-not-take-that-yaw./) by [darshb34](https://answers.ros.org/users/52465/darshb34/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to change the origin, you need to change `map_zone.pgm` as well.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [darshb34](https://answers.ros.org/users/52465/darshb34/) on 2020-11-06**:
@miura can you point me how to change map_zone.pgm? Are any opensource tools available?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-11-06**:
You can use [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/).

[Documentation on rotation](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-rotate.html)